# Display distinct values and take max in Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, where I would like to show only the max distinct values.

DATA

```
type    power
a_b     5
a_c     6
a_c     4
a_c     4
a_b     6
a_b     9
```

DESIRED

```
type    power
a_b     9
a_c     6
```

DOING

```
df1 = df.unique
df2 = max(df1)
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Isn't the max of a_b 9 in your example? And what outcome are you getting from your current attempt?

Comment: Yes I updated. Let me update the result I am getting

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: Please [include a minimal data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-to-provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-your-dataframe-with-to-clipboard) as part of your MRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `groupby`:

```
df.groupby('type', as_index=False)['power'].max()
```